# my python app doesn't work and give a None as answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i would like to know why my app is giving me that error i've tried already everything what i found in google and still have not idea why is that happeing

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/XLTOK-Charging-Transfer-Charger-Nintendo/dp/B0828RYQ7W/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=type+c&qid=1598485860&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUE3TDNSNUlITUNKTUMmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTAwNDg4MTMyUlFQN0Y4RllGQzE2JmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTAxNDk0NzMyMFNLSUdPU0taVUpRJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ=='

headers = {"User-agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle")


print(title)
```

When called:

```
C:\Proyecto nuevo>Python main.py
None
```

So if anyone would like to help me will be amazing!!

Comment: Which error? Printing "None" is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the webpage code (the one your are trying to scrape), you will find that it is pretty much all javascript that populates the webpage when it loads. The requests library gets this code and doesn't run it. Your "find title" gets none because the code doesn't contain that.

To scrape this page you will have to run the javascript on it. You can check out the Selenium WebDriver in python to do this.

Comment: Well for being honest I’m new on python and I’m just following some guy code but for some reason my code doesn’t work and his does so I was wondering what I was doing wrong cuz I’m sure it can be done in another way but I wanted to know why mine one doesn’t work

Comment: The code you are using might work for other web pages, but this page you are trying to access is written in javascript. This means that most of the HTML objects are created when the page is loaded. Beautiful soup doesn't load the page, it only downloads the code. @CarlosRodriguez

Comment: So what it would be the right way to do it? If you don’t mind...

Comment: Mentioned it in the answer, you can use Selenium WebDriver. It will run a browser and run the webpage allowing your to access the HTML generated by the javascript. Plenty of guides on how: https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/ @CarlosRodriguez